# Styling your buttons in React native

Tags: css, react-native

I would like to implement styling to my two buttons ! However ,nothing is changing to them !! I tried to pass styling via The view style above but nothing changes !! this is the code

**App.js**

```
      <Text style={{marginTop:130,marginLeft:60,fontSize:25,marginVertical:150,borderRadius:2}}>Welcome to Daret !</Text>
        <Button style={styles.signin}
          title="Sign In"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Sign In')}
        />
        <Button title="Registration" style= {styles.registration}
         onPress= {()=>navigation.navigate('Registration')}/>
    </View>
```

**Style**

```
      marginTop:50,
      width: 90,
      borderRadius:2 

    },

    registration : {

      width:20  ,
      borderRadius:2,
      alignItems:'center',
      backgroundColor:'black'

    }
```

Comment: In vain , In vain :/

Comment: @Tim you deserve credits Bro (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

The standard [React Native Button](https://reactnative.dev/docs/button) does not have a prop to change its style, as you can see if you have a look into the [Button Code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/ce0edca620d49597aa73c71a68b70efa170bc828/Libraries/Components/Button.js).

**Solution:**

Instead of the standard buttons, try to use any Touchable (e.g. [TouchableHighligt](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight) or [TouchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity)). There you can pass a style object to customize as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use this prop `buttonStyle` as you are using `style` as used below

```
      <Button
        title='Login' 
        buttonStyle={{
          backgroundColor:'red'
        }}
      />
```

Comment: can you create a `fiddle` or `pen`, in that way i can help you better ?

Comment: you meant creating a file  where I will tap my code and share the link

Comment: yess exactly, `jsfiddle` and `codepen` are easily available and free ones